# QML: How to create a nested model with javascript?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

My goal is to take json data that contains nested comments(like on hackernews or reddit) and display it in my qml app.
I have found how to create a tree view from a nested model:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30521

And now I'm trying to figure out how to build a nested model using javascript.
I need something like this:

```
ListModel {
            id: treemodel
            ListElement { text: "Level 1, Node 1" }
            ListElement {
                text: "Level 1, Node 2"
                children: [
                    ListElement { text: "Level 2, Node 1"
                        children: [
                            ListElement { text: "Level 3, Node 1" }
                        ]
                    },
                    ListElement { text: "Level 2, Node 2" }
                ]
            }
            ListElement { text: "Level 1, Node 3" }
        }
```

I can add top level elements to the model like so:

```
        function createCommentsModel() {
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                treemodel.append ({
                    text: "Level 1, Node " + i
                });
            }
        }
```

But how do I add children to these elements(and subchildren to these children, etc, recursively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this, but I was unable to create a ListElement with the Qt.createQmlObject(). 
So instead I get the last node in the elements array, and recursively add children to that.

I'm not sure what the format of the comments look like, but I believe that with some modifications that the below code could help you achieve what you want.

```
function createCommentsModel() {
    treemodel.append ({
        text: "Level 1, Node " + i
    });
    //Get last appended node
    var level1node = treemodel.get(treemodel.count - 1);
    //Add children recursively
    addNode(level1node, 2, 1, 3)
}    

function addNode(node, level, nodenr, maxLevel) {
    if(node === undefined || level > maxLevel) {
        return {}
    }

    node.elements.append({
                             text: "Level " + level +", Node " + nodenr,
                             elements: []
                         });
    var child = node.elements.get(node.elements.count - 1);
    var returnValue = addNode(child, level + 1, nodenr, maxLevel);
    return returnValue;
}
```